# How do we set TTL for cell in Load Data to HBase Table using completebulkload

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs, hbase

I have a use case where I need to use Bulk Import data to HBase.
I was following this link -> http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#completebulkload
from the official site, everything is working fine but setting TTL option is not very clear anyone used it before?

Mapreduce tool hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv

Answer (score 0):

You provide ttl option while creating hbase table to delete lines with older ttl automatically. 
If you set this option while creating a table, then you can use
`-Dimporttsv.timestamp=currentTimeAsLong - use the specified timestamp for the import` option in importtsv command.

Comment: I tried this earlier but the records are not getting deleted after the TTL expires. Example 
-Dimporttsv.timestamp=000300
as this feature expects fix 6 length value so have to add additional "000" in the beginning, but it never gets expired (Cell should get deleted)

Comment: Additionally, -Dimporttsv.timestamp=currentTimeAsLong this one is for insert timestamp not for ttl. For ttl its HBASE_CELL_TTL as an argument to be passed when using bulkload jar.